# What are and how do I earn Feats of Strength in StarCraft 2

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

On the bottom of the achievements menu is an option for *Feats of Strength*. When I click this option, the window it brings up is entirely blank, but does have a drop down filter at the top.

Are *Feats of Strength* hidden achievements? If not what exactly are they? How do I go about earning them?

Do they reward battle.net points?

Comment: In WoW these are rare, event driven achievements, so it's unlikely they are currently available

Comment: There are a few feats of strength available.

Comment: You may have to wait until Festivus.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a list of the Feats of Strength available in StarCraft 2:

### Wings of Liberty

**The Scenic Route**

Destroy all Zerg structures in "The Devil's Playground" mission on Normal difficulty.

[image: The Scenic Route]

**You'ze So Crazy!**

Destroy all Protoss structures in the "Welcome to the Jungle" mission on Normal difficulty.

[image: You'ze So Crazy!]

**Monster Mash**

Use the A.R.E.S. to kill the Brutalisk in the "Piercing the Shroud" mission on Normal difficulty.

[image: Monster Mash]

**Hot Shot**

Finish a Qualification Round with an undefeated record.

### Events

**BlizzConqueror 2010**

Purchase tickets to Blizzard’s convention taking place in Anaheim, California on October 22 & 23, 2010.

**BlizzConqueror 2011**

Purchase tickets to Blizzard’s convention taking place in Anaheim, California on October 21 & 22, 2011.

**15 Years of StarCraft!**

Play a game of StarCraft II during the 15th anniversary celebration.

[image: 15 Years of StarCraft!]

### Collector's Edition Perks

**Devoted Fan**

Purchase StarCraft II Wings of Liberty Collector's Edition.

[image: Devoted Fan]

**Cataclysmic Devotion**

Purchase the Collector's Edition of World of Warcraft: Cataclysm.

[image: Cataclysmic Devotion]

**Diabolical Devotion**

Purchase the Diablo III Collector’s Edition.

[image: Diabolical Devotion]

**Pandamonian Devotion**

Purchase World of Warcraft Cataclysm Collector’s Edition.

[image: Pandamonian Devotion]

**HeartCore Devotion**

Purchase StarCraft II Heart of the Swarm Collector's Edition.

[image: HeartCore Devotion]

### Heart of the Swarm Beta

**Heart of the Swarm Beta Protoss Level <s>30</s> 5**

Reach Level <s>30</s> 5 as Protoss in the Heart of the Swarm Beta.

**Heart of the Swarm Beta Terran Level <s>30</s> **

Reach Level <s>30</s> 5 as Terran in the Heart of the Swarm Beta.

**Heart of the Swarm Beta Zerg Level <s>30</s> 5**

Reach Level <s>30</s> 5 as Zerg in the Heart of the Swarm Beta.

The level requirements for the feats of strength earned during the [Heart of Swarm beta were changed on January 31, 2013](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/8528973).

No Battle.net points are earned from the above Feats of Strength.

Comment: And for those that are trying for these, remember that you have multiple chances to earn Hot Shot: each time you get a new partner for 2v2 or 3v3 or 4v4 you need to go through a qualification round again.

Comment: I think it's pretty lame that there is an achievement for buying the collectors edition.  I understand *why* they did it, but to me achievements should be something that can be accomplished by anyone who bought any version of the game.

Comment: @Matt -- that's why it's *not* an achievement. Limited opportunity Feats of Strength occur in WoW (Blizzard's other game with achievements) as well, such as logging in on WoW's 5th anniversary, or acquiring Atiesh (no longer attainable).

Comment: Great answer, do the feats of strength award battle.net points for being completed?

Comment: Didn't realize they were different things.  They seem very similar to me.

Comment: @ahsteele, @Matt, they do *not* award battle.net points, nor do they provide character profiles / decals. *That* is what differentiates them. The one has a (semi)tangible reward, and the other is merely for flexing your e-reputation.

Comment: Is it the complete list of the feats?

Comment: @Raven While they do not award battle.net points, they can reward profiles and decals, as in the case of "devoted fan", there are custom portraits and decals for them. But I guess you could say that the portraits and decals are seperate rewards for the collector's edition, not part of the feat of strength.

Comment: Note that there is a new Feat of Strength: BlizzConqueror 2010

Answer (score 1):

Just for the future: If blizzard applies the same logic as in World of Warcraft the Feats of Strength can be past achievements that cannot be done now (i.e: killing onyxia at lvl 60) or are really rare (server first level 80)

Remember also that feats of strength doesn't reward any kind of point, it just more a "I was there" badge

Comment: The current SC2 Feats of Strength fall into two categories: 1. Limited opportunity (Devoted Fan) 2. Difficult to earn (Monster Mash) In either case, they could be considered "above and beyond what is expected" I guess you could say that about all achievements, but these are generally further than that. WoW feats of strength go into the same categories 1. (Operation: Gnomeregan) 2. (Insane in the Membrane).